# unable to access all laravel routes

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am not able to access other laravel routes when I am accessing the route through which I am reading about 100 files line by line and then comparing the lines one by one with a standard data set file to save the data in db. Once I run this route, which takes almost 30 minutes to complete, I am unable to access any other route. Once that is finished or I turn off the wamp server(MySQL service) then I can access all routes.

This is the function which reads the data from around 100 files and send to another function for comparison

```
public function readData(){
        $filename = public_path() . '/online/daraz/smartphones.txt';
        $onlineData = file_get_contents($filename);

        $di = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(public_path().'/scrap/');

        foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

            if($file->getExtension() == 'txt' && $file->isFile()){
                /*if(strtolower(explode(".", $file->getFileName())[0]) == $brandName){*/

                    try
                    {
                        $onlyFileName = strtolower(explode(".", $file->getFilename())[0]);
                        $gsmData = file_get_contents($filename);
                        //$this->saveData($gsmData, $onlyFileName);
                        $this->compareData($gsmData, $onlineData, $onlyFileName);

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException $exception)
                    {
                        die("The file doesn't exist");
                    }
                //}
            }
            /*if(@is_array(getimagesize($file))){
                echo 'true';
            } else {
                echo 'false';
            }*/
        }

    }
```

Comment: sorry but what is the problem here? Dont acces that route it is probably using all the server resources.

Comment: did you try to increase the ressources of your wamp server? This might speed up the stuff. You shuold also think about running long running tasks in batch jobs instead of keeping the connection open.